# GeoServer Image Pyramid Fails?

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to build an image pyramid data store in geoserver 2.14 running windows 10.

I have built the image pyramid as per these instructions: https://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/creating-a-pyramid-with-gdal-reltile-for-serving-with-geoserver

My pyramid properties file looks like this:
Name=satellite

```
Levels=10.0,10.0 20.0,20.0
LevelsDirs = 0 1
LevelsNum=2
Envelope2D = 1084000.0,4722000.0 2092000.0,6217280.0
```

File structure is

```
c:\new\pyramid.properties

C:\new\0\0.dbf
C:\new\0\0.fix
C:\new\0\0.prj
C:\new\0\0.properties
C:\new\0\0.qix
C:\new\0\0.shp
C:\new\0\0.shx
C:\new\0\0.satellite_01_21.tif.....

c:\new\pyramid.properties
C:\new\1\1.dbf
C:\new\1\1.fix
C:\new\1\1.prj
C:\new\1\1.properties
C:\new\1\1.qix
C:\new\1\1.shp
C:\new\1\1.shx
C:\new\1\1.satellite_01_10.tif.....
```

Both folders 0 and 1, can read in as an imagemosaic, however I cannot get image pyramid to connect to anything

Everytime I hit connect I get the following error:

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: 
Failed to create reader from file://C:\new\pyramid.properties and hints 
Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@12f7942 
EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@182b120[Running, 
pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] 
System defaults: GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = 
null FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 
FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@1ec8458 
STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true 
LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http
```

My research on this folder suggests a permissions issue with tomcat but I have been unable to find any installation of tomcat on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I missed the need for a projection file at the root directory at the bottom of slide six herein https://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/creating-a-pyramid-with-gdal-reltile-for-serving-with-geoserver

Adding a file with the suffix .prj with the following content resolved the issue

```
PROJCS["NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000",
  GEOGCS["NZGD2000",
    DATUM["New Zealand Geodetic Datum 2000",
      SPHEROID["GRS 1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
      TOWGS84[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6167"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4167"]],
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 173.0],
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996],
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 1600000.0],
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 10000000.0],
  UNIT["m", 1.0],
  AXIS["Easting", EAST],
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","2193"]]
```